# How can i sort a list by the second item descending and first one ascending?

Tags: python, sorting, stable-sort

I have a list like this:

```
list_results=[('Horror', 2), ('Romance', 2), ('Comedy', 2), ('History', 2), ('Adventure', 1), ('Action', 3)]
```

I wish to sort the number in descending order and if numbers were the same, according to the name in ascending order.

I tried the following code:

```
sortlist=sorted(list_results,key=lambda x:(x[1],x[0]))
```

and the reverse but I couldn't figure out to do it.

The answer that I'm looking for is:

```
[('Action', 3), ('Comedy', 2) ,('History', 2),('Horror', 2), ('Romance', 2), ('Adventure', 1), ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First sort the list by the first item, then by the second item:

```
list_results = sorted(list_results, key=lambda x:x[0])
list_results = sorted(list_results, key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)
```

or better yet without copying:

```
import operator

list_results.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(0))
list_results.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

Python's sort algorithm is [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort). It is a [stable algorithm](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sort-stability-and-complex-sorts) meaning if 2 values are the same, they'll stay in their original order.

If you sort alphabetically first, and then by the priority, the list will be sorted according to the alphabet, then re-sorted according to priority with alphabet being secondary.

Comment: *""or better yet without copying:"* Yes, the second version is better. There is no good reason to use `sorted` if you're going to discard the original list anyway. What you could do, if you don't want to discard the original list, is used `sorted` the first time, then `.sort` on the result the second time.

Comment: Another alternative is to sort only once but with an appropriate tuple as key: `sorted(list_results,key=lambda x:(-x[1],x[0]))`. Note the minus sign on the numeric value.

Comment: @Stef I wanted to show the OP that his way of thinking was correct, and then show him the best way.

Comment: @Stef I agree with your (-x) solution as well. As timsort is O(n) for sorted data, I believe it will actually be faster to sort twice as you do not incur the lambda overhead. Interesting to check it.

Comment: There's a bit of confusion here. If you sort with a certain key, then sort a second time with a different key, you can't say the second sort is "O(n) because the data was already sorted". The data was not sorted at all, from the second sort key's point of view.

Comment: Which of the two is faster probably depends on the size of the list. The keys are only computed once per item, so sorting twice is probably slower than sorting only once. Comparing tuple keys might be slower than comparing integer keys, but using the tuples has the added benefit that strings only need to be compared when there is a tie on the integers - whereas if you sort twice, you really do need to compare lots of strings (and string comparison is slower than integer comparison). So if the list is long and the strings can be long too, my money is on the single sort with a tuple key.

Comment: Of course only an actual timed experiment could decide it - but the result might depend on the data (length of the list, lengths of the strings, lengths of common prefixes in the strings, etc)

Comment: Another question to choose between the two is: how easy to understand are they? Of course that's a matter of preference. Personally I find the tuple version often clearer, because it's clear what key is more important (the second element of the tuple is only there for tie-breaks). Whereas with multiple sorts, I need to take a second to remember that it's the last sort that matters most, and the first sort was the tie breaker.

Comment: As there is a limited number of values for the second item, chances are you'll find long natural runs which is what timesort is optimized on. True, it's not sorted from the point of view of the second item, but the possible values for the second item are an order of magnitude smaller than the first.

Comment: Testing proved to break even at 500 strings containing 5-10 random letters, and numbers ranging from 1-10. Above 500 strings or for larger number variety your solution scales better, below that my solution seems better. I believe you're completely correct that requiring only one sort makes a large difference later on, as the lambda scales on an O(n) * const and the double sort goes forO(n*logn). Please add it as a possible answer :-)

Comment: *"I wanted to show the OP that his way of thinking was correct, and then show him the best way."* Note the OP used a differently-named list for the result of sorted. To get the same result when sorting twice, you could mix `sorted` and `list.sort`: `sortlist = sorted(list_results, key=lambda x:x[0]); sortlist.sort(key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)`

Answer (score 2):

You want to sort according to two criteria, with one criterion acting as a tie-breaker for the other. Since python's `sorted` and `list.sort` are guaranteed to be stable sorts, one solution is to sort the list twice: first sort it by the tie-breaker, then sort it by the main criterion. [This is @Bharel's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70314754/3080723)

Another possibility is to sort only once, using a tuple as the key. Python's `sorted` and `list.sort` both offer a `reverse= True or False` argument to specify a sort in increasing or decreasing order; but in your case, we want to sort in decreasing order with respect to the first criterion, and increasing order with respect to the second criterion. The `reverse` keyword is not helpful because it is all-or-nothing: it will not allow us to choose which criterion to reverse.

Since the first criterion is numeric (an integer), a simple trick to sort in reverse order is to negate it with a minus sign:

```py
sortlist = sorted(list_results, key=lambda x:(-x[1], x[0]))
```

Note the `-x[1]` instead of just `x[1]`.

Here are two arguments in favour of sorting once by a tuple, rather than twice:

- When sorting according to `(-x[1], x[0])`, it is immediately clear that `-x[1]` is the main criterion, and `x[0]` is only a tie-breaker. By contrast, if you sort twice, someone reading your code needs to take a second to understand that the last sort is the most important, and the previous sort is only there as a tie-breaker relying on `sorted` being a stable sort.
- If the list is long, sorting once with a tuple key is probably faster than sorting twice with simple keys. This is especially true because the second key is a string; comparing string is slower than comparing integers. If you use tuples, the strings will only be compared for two items who are ex aequo on the first key; but if you sort twice, about `n log(n)` string comparisons will be performed in the first sort.

If your list is small, it probably doesn't matter which version is faster (unless you're repeatedly sorting lots of small lists...), so it's a matter of preference and readability.